# UIActivityItemSource Protocol optional methods not working in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented `UIActivityItemSource` protocol to share url in facebook using `UIActivityViewController`. Required methods `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` and `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` are called by `UIActivityViewController`.  But optional method below to display thumbnail image in the preview page is not called.

```
- (UIImage *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController thumbnailImageForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType suggestedSize:(CGSize)size
```

This code works in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could be a bug on Apple's implementation. Have you tried using 8.3 beta SDK? If still reproduces, open a bug report and post the radar number here.

Comment: i'm having the same issue, have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Add self to activity items when creating UIActivityViewController:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
```